# Playing multiple audio files rails' audio_tag: is there a way to play all the files from one player?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I'm new to rails. I am building a site that has a function where the admin can upload audio files, that will then be played in the background.

I am using carrierwave for file upload and rails' audio_tag for the player, but I am running into trouble when the database has more than one audio file.

This is the relevant code from the view:

```html
<%= audio_tag Track.pluck(:file), controls: true, autoplay: true %>
```

which evaluates to: " <%= audio_tag [file1, file2, file3...], controls: true, autoplay: true %>

(The .pluck method is extracting the file names from each track and storing them in an array of strings.)

And my Track model (carrierwave uploader is called 'FileUploader'):

```html
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :file, presence: true
 mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

The model is 'Track' with one attribute 'file.'

How can I get the audio player to play multiple audio files, without pre-knowledge of what the file(s) will be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try making
    :file => [file1, file2, file3]
I'm not sure what you've got for the key :file but here's the syntax for audio_tag and multiple sources

```
audio_tag("sound.wav", "sound.mid")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I probably should have clarifies (I'll edit my post now), the files are coming from user input, so I don't know how many there will be...